# w2ui & Node Postgres Database connection

Tags: javascript, json, postgresql, w2ui

Hey guys im coding a project using w2ui and im trying get data from a postgres database and display it in a grid on w2ui, the connection to the database that ive done is successful however it's not in the same format as expect from the w2ui grid.Which should be tableitem:"tabledata" How do i accomplish this. Below is my code for queries.js

```
const Pool = require('pg').Pool
const pool = new Pool({
  user: 'postgres',
  host: 'jdbc:postgresql://172.24.143.61/ayelab_data',
  database: 'ayelab_data',
  password: '*****',
  port: 5432,
})

const getOrders = (request, response) => {
    pool.query('SELECT branchcode,ordercode,patient_lastname,patient_firstname,doctorsname,date_entered,departuredate,urgent,status FROM orders', (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        throw error
      }
      response.status(200).json(results.rows)
    })
  }

  module.exports = {
    getOrders,

  }
```

and this is my w2ui grid code

```
$(function () {
    $('#grid').w2grid({ 
        name: 'grid', 

        columns: [      
            { field: 'blank', caption: '', size: '10px' },          
            { field: 'branch', caption: 'Branch', size: '120px' },
            { field: 'order', caption: 'Order',size: '120px', editable: { type: 'text' }},
            { field: 'lname', caption: 'Last Name', size: '120px', editable: { type: 'text' } },
            { field: 'fname', caption: 'First Name', size: '120px', editable: { type: 'text' } },
            { field: 'physician', caption: 'Physician', size: '120px' },
            { field: 'dateadded', caption: 'Date Added', size: '120px',editable: { type: 'date' } },
            { field: 'completdate', caption: 'Completion Date', size: '120px',editable: { type: 'date' }},
            { field: 'priority', caption: 'Priority', size: '120px' },
            { field: 'status', caption: 'Status', size: '120px' }
        ]

    });  
    w2ui['grid'].load('node-api-postgres/queries.js');  
});
```

Comment: can someone reply?

Answer (score 0):

I always end up answering my own questions... 
changed the host to  `host: '172.24.143.61',`
and also called the `getOrder` function in a request

```
app.get('/queries',(response,resp) => {
  db.getOrders(response,resp);
});
```